# how to access low level metadata from java api

Tags: java, sas, sas-metadata

I have tried to extract metadata for visual exploration objects using     `com.sas.metadata.remote.MdOMIUtil#getMetadataObjectsSubset`

method, but all I get is high level information like its name, fqid and the list of imported data sources. Is there any way to extract information about the individual visualizations contained in the visual exploration and also the details about the metrics and dimensions used?